# iOS Facebook Login from Phonegap application crashes app

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use facebook-connect as a plugin in my phonegap (cordova 2.5) application on iOS. It worked all well, we tested the application on various devices and released it to the store. It passed the review and baaammm: The facebook login is not working anymore on some devices.

When loading the Facebook-plugin all goes well. But as soon as the Facebook-App launches itself the screen changes to a white screen with the blue Facebook top header on it, but no text appears. The error-logs of the device says:

```
class: NSException; name: NSInternalInconsistencyException; reason: 
Invalid update_invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained 
in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections 
contained in the table view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of 
sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 1 deleted).;
```

The full error log is attached below.

Does any one know what could cause that issue? Afterwards you have to kill the application by hand to get it working again. Uninstalling the complete application and reinstalling it from the store solved the problem, so it seems to only occur if you just update your application.

Thanks for your help!

Sebastian

```
May  2 14:44:16 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Warning>: Previously encountered exception: Device: iPhone; app_version: 6.0.2; build_number: 183159; ios_version: 5.1.1; model: iPhone; load_address: 0x11000; jail_broken: no; class: NSException; name: NSInternalInconsistencyException; reason: Invalid update_ invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 1 deleted).; time: 1367498312; backtrace:

Thread #0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x371b98a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34ebe259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreFoundation                      0x371b9789 +[NSException raise_format_] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x379f83a3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod_object_file_lineNumber_description_] + 90
4   UIKit                               0x30f44b45 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext_] + 8304
5   UIKit                               0x30fbb209 -[UITableView _updateSections_updateAction_withRowAnimation_] + 308
6   UIKit                               0x3105fccd -[UITableView reloadSections_withRowAnimation_] + 32
7   Facebook                            0x004b0aa3 _ZNSt3__13mapIiPN6webrtc7MapItemENS_4lessIiEENS_9allocatorINS_4pairIKiS3_EEEEEixERS8_ + 1042030
8   Facebook                            0x004b0209 _ZNSt3__13mapIiPN6webrtc7MapItemENS_4lessIiEENS_9allocatorINS_4pairIKiS3_EEEEEixERS8_ + 1039828
9   Facebook                            0x00a5a86b _ZNSt3__13mapINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEES6_NS_4lessIS6_EENS4_INS_4pairIKS6_S6_EEEEE16__find_equal_keyERPNS_16__tree_node_baseIPvEERSA_ + 1280626
10  Facebook                            0x00649e2b _ZNSt3__113__vector_baseI17ContextAwareBlockNS_9allocatorIS1_EEED2Ev + 1078378
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x302d9c59 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x302e4e91 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 196
13  CoreFoundation                      0x3718c2ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
14  CoreFoundation                      0x3710f4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
15  CoreFoundation                      0x3710f36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
16  GraphicsServices                    0x338ce439 GSEventRunModal + 136
17  UIKit                               0x30ebbcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
18  Facebook                            0x000132f5 _mh_execute_header + 8949
19  Facebook                            0x000132b8 _mh_execute_header + 8888

Thread #1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313603a8 kevent + 24


May  2 14:44:18 iPhone-von-Felipe com.apple.accountsd[196] <Notice>: Exiting...


May  2 14:44:22 iPhone-von-Felipe sandboxd[198] <Notice>: Facebook(155) deny file-write-create /private/var/mobile/Applications/AC8F9F4D-8CC6-4F0F-BDF8-97EAF587EF1B


May  2 14:44:23 iPhone-von-Felipe sandboxd[198] <Notice>: Facebook(155) deny file-write-create /private/var/mobile/Applications/AC8F9F4D-8CC6-4F0F-BDF8-97EAF587EF1B

May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x13c0][155] <Notice>: May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0


May  2 14:44:26 iPhone-von-Felipe Facebook[155] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
```

**EDIT**
We solved it. It was caused by requiring read and write permissions simultanously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it. It was caused by requiring read and write permissions simultanously.